# General mathematical definition of a score

Tags: pca, terminology, dimensionality-reduction, embeddings

I understand what scores are in PCA, in particular [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202578/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-variable-scores-in-matlabs-pca?answertab=active#tab-top) gives a good mathematical formulation:

> (Scores) are projections of the centred data in the linear space
>   defined by the eigenvectors.

But the concept of *scores*, as representations of the original data in a new space does not have to be PCA-specific - other linear spaces can be identified with other techniques. Does the concept of scores have a general mathematical definition outside of PCA? Specifically, I wonder if there is one that would accommodate nonlinear techniques as well - the way I see it, techniques such as non-linear PCA also produce something that is analogous to scores, just that they can have higher dimensionality than the original data.

So, is there one mathematical definition *to rule them all*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a score definition that "rules them all," but consider the notion shown in here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28715259. There, the first PC score is defined as a linear combination (score) that maximizes the sum of $R^2$ values when regressing each of the original variables on the score. As such, the awkward and not-easily understood "variance maximization" and "unit length constraint" concepts can be discarded completely. The first two scores are any two linear combinations that similarly maximize the sum of $R^2$s in the multiple regression model using the two scores as predictors; thus, not only are unit length and variance maximization concepts unnecessary, but so is orthogonality.

This approach could be modified to the nonlinear case, see https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~draper/eBay-Google-2013-breiman-friedman-1985.pdf for nonlinear transformations (scores) that maximize the $R^2$ in a regression with a single dependent variable. I would imagine that such an approach could also be used to maximize the sum of $R^2$ values as in linear principal components analysis, and that this would indeed be  very useful dimension reduction technique, with fewer scores explaining a greater (average) percentage of variation in the original variables, but I am not aware that anyone has done it.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page for [disambiguating use of the word "score"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score) doesn't even seem to include that use, but it does include several other uses of the word in mathematics or statistics. The one I suspect that you would find most frequently used on this site is "[the gradient of the log-likelihood function with respect to the parameter vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics))," as used in the [score test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test) for models fit by maximum likelihood.

Comment: These aren't the scores I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

PCA is nothing but a new system of orthogonal coordinates, which happens to be a linear transformation of an old system of coordinates. You take the old coordinates $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ in an original Euclidian system $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$ and linearly transform it into a new system of coordinates (factors) $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)=Ae$. The scores are coordinates in new system $(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$.